# Date picker + Segmented control + some labels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

Here is how the page should look like:

[image]

It should have the following functionality:
- By clicking the period on segmented control start date gets the value of present time - the interva and end date gets the value of the present time. 
- By selecting one of the labels Start/End, you are able to change their date with date picker.

For now, I have implemented segmented control and date picker.

It would be good if you could give me some pointers about label implementation. How to make them selectable, change color on selection, etc. Maybe those are not labels, but some other control. Every help is appreciated :)

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Those should not be labels, but buttons.  You can customize the UIButton to look like what you have above, and supporting the color change is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

[startButton addTarget: self action: @selector(stcolor:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[endButton addTarget: self action: @selector(edcolor:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(id)stcolor{
   startButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor whitecolor];
   endbutton.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

}
-(id)edcolor{
   startButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor whitecolor];
   endbutton.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

}